# Allow access to web server across multiple internal networks [LAMP]

Tags: apache, routes, lamp, intranet

My business network is comprised of four locations across my farm, being my house, feed shed, cold storage and vet (animal welfare), due to the size of the property, the network is fibre to the house, then broadcasting a long range wifi signal with repeaters across the property to the other locations; to reach the feed shed this goes through two repeaters.

I have an R-PI running as a LAMP server, which is accessible on metrics.local and on its IP range 192.66.66.XXX (no idea why this range, that was what the original network engineer set up). The LAMP is hosting a wordpress website which captures internal metrics people record; such as feed used, we have no issues with this in the main residence. I have allowed port 80 without any restrictions as its an internal network through apache.

The problem is, whoever configured the network originally put other locations on separate domains, being 192.168.X.XXX, where the X is a different domain, so I have three LAN networks being 192.66.66, 192.168.1 and 192.168.2.

I have raised this with the network engineering team who have advised we have no firewalls blocking access between the networks and this is not a networking issue, but a server/apache config issue.

I've added routes to my LAMP server to allow the 192 range to connect to my server and I can ping the device from the computers on these other networks, however I cannot access metrics.local, with the browsers simply saying "cannot find the site".

I have reached the end of my ability to google the solution, with most routing topics being about adding additional domains to the LAMP, not allowing network access.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to route packets to a different networks.

192.166.66.XXX

192.168.1.XXX

192.168.2.XXX

All of these are different networks. For same network, packets can be routed by direct switches, but your network admins need the route all of the network t talk to each other using their own network gateway.

alternatively your network/sysadmin can forward your IP so it gets expose to other network, in this way it will be accessable to everyone using any one single assigned IP which works in all three network.

This is how routing works
[image]